# gmail api: Get latest email in the thread

Tags: python, gmail-api

Currently, my script prints out the recipient's email. However, it only returns me the first email in the thread. I want it to return me the latest email in the thread. How do I do that?

```
messages = service.users().threads().list(userId='me').execute().get('threads', [])
    for message in messages:
        if search in message['snippet']:
            # print(message['id'])
            message_id = message['id']
            full_message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message_id, format="raw").execute()
            msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(full_message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))
            mime_msg = email.message_from_bytes(msg_str)
            y = re.findall(r'Delivered-To: (\S+)', str(mime_msg))
            print(y[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You need to get the last message out of the thread array returned by `users: threads.list`.*

#### More Information:

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.threads/list#response-body), the `users: threads.list` method returns an array of Message resources per thread. A representation of this resource is as follows:

```json
{
  "threads": [
    {
      "id": string,
      "snippet": string,
      "historyId": string,
      "messages": [
        {
          object (Message)
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "resultSizeEstimate": integer
```

The `messages` array contain all the messages in the thread, ordered by `internalDate`.

The `internalDate` value os this response is defined as such:

> **`internalDate`:** `string (int64 format)`
>
> > The internal message creation timestamp (epoch ms), which determines ordering in the inbox. For normal SMTP-received email, this represents the time the message was originally accepted by Google, which is more reliable than the Date header. However, for API-migrated mail, it can be configured by client to be based on the Date header.

Knowing that messages with higher `internalDate` values are more recent, we can use this to retrieve the *latest* email in the thread:

```py
messages = service.users().threads().list(userId='me').execute().get('threads', [])

for message in messages:
    if search in message['snippet']:
        # add/modify the following lines:
        thread = service.users().threads().get(userId='me', id=message['id'], fields='messages(id,internalDate)').execute() #.get( [])
        last = len(thread['messages']) - 1
        message_id = thread['messages'][last]['id']

        # non-modified code:
        full_message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message_id, format="raw").execute()
        msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(full_message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))
        mime_msg = email.message_from_bytes(msg_str)
        y = re.findall(r'Delivered-To: (\S+)', str(mime_msg))
        print(y[0])
```

#### References:

- [REST Resource: users.messages | Gmail API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#Message)
- [Method: users.threads.list | Gmail API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.threads/list)
- [Method: users.threads.get | Gmail API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.threads/get)

Comment: Thanks, @rafa! Does it work the same way if I want to retrieve the latest 2 emails in the thread?